# Confidence-Interval - Proof the Upper and Lower limit

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, inference

Given two limits $ L(x)$ and $U(x)$ that satisfy the follow condition:

$P_{\theta}(L(x) \le \theta) = 1 - \alpha_1$, $P_{\theta}(U(x)\ge \theta) = 1 - \alpha_2 $.

Knowing that $ L(x) \le U(x)$ for all $ x_{i} $, proof that

$P_{\theta}(L(x) \le \theta \le U(x)) = 1 - \alpha_1 - \alpha_2. $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$P_\theta(L(x) \le \theta \le U(x))=P_\theta(\theta \le U(x)) - P_\theta(\theta < L(x))$$

Try to express the terms on the RHS in terms of $\alpha_i$.

Comment: What are the terms of the RHS? Can you give me the extense name?

Comment: find $P_\theta ( \theta \le U(x))$ and $P_\theta (\theta < L(x))$.

Comment: RHS = Right Hand Side, I wasn't getting that. Thank you!!!